# cannot login User Mode Linux (UML)

Tags: linux, user-mode-linux

For my `UML (user mode linux)`, I have built a Debian based root file system and added a user "uml". But when I am trying to log in UML, it was not accepted:

```
<snip>
(none) login: uml

Ubuntu 5.10 "Breezy Badger" (none) tty0

(none) login:
</snip>
```

My UML was built from Linux 2.6.27 source tree.   The root-fs was
created as:   `debootstrap --arch i386 breezy <my-dir>`

After created the `root-fs`,  I chroot into it and did "adduser uml".
  But why the UML did not accept the user name "uml"?

Btw, I also tried "root" but also not accepted.

thanks.

UPDATE:  here is the full log I have during the login session:

```
./linux mem=128M ubda=/nobackup/hxu2/uml/debian-2
Locating the bottom of the address space ... 0x0
Locating the top of the address space ... 0xffffd000
Core dump limits :
        soft - 104857600
        hard - NONE
Checking that ptrace can change system call numbers...OK
Checking syscall emulation patch for ptrace...missing
Checking for tmpfs mount on /dev/shm...OK
Checking PROT_EXEC mmap in /dev/shm/...OK
Checking for the skas3 patch in the host:
  - /proc/mm...not found: No such file or directory
  - PTRACE_FAULTINFO...not found
  - PTRACE_LDT...not found
UML running in SKAS0 mode
[    0.000000] Linux version 2.6.27 (hxu2@sjc-ads-445) (gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)) #1 Sat Jan 26 21:41:07 PST 2013
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: mem=128M ubda=/nobackup/hxu2/uml/debian-2 root=98:0
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 512 (order: 9, 2048 bytes)
[42949372.960000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[42949372.960000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[42949372.960000] Memory: 126832k available
[42949372.960000] Calibrating delay loop... 3774.87 BogoMIPS (lpj=18874368)
[42949373.250000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
[42949373.250000] Checking for host processor cmov support...Yes
[42949373.250000] Checking that host ptys support output SIGIO...Yes
[42949373.250000] Checking that host ptys support SIGIO on close...No, enabling workaround
[42949373.250000] net_namespace: 288 bytes
[42949373.250000] /usr/include/linux/aio_abi.h not present during build
[42949373.250000] 2.6 host AIO support not used - falling back to I/O thread
[42949373.250000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[42949373.280000] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[42949373.440000] IP route cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[42949373.440000] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[42949373.440000] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[42949373.440000] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[42949373.440000] TCP reno registered
[42949373.510000] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[42949373.510000] Checking host MADV_REMOVE support...<3>MADV_REMOVE failed, err = -22
[42949373.510000] Can't release memory to the host - memory hotplug won't be supported
[42949373.510000] mconsole (version 2) initialized on /users/hxu2/.uml/DytWds/mconsole
[42949373.510000] Host TLS support detected
[42949373.510000] Detected host type: x86_64 (GDT indexes 12 to 15)
[42949373.510000] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.1
[42949373.510000] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[42949373.510000] msgmni has been set to 248
[42949373.510000] io scheduler noop registered
[42949373.510000] io scheduler anticipatory registered (default)
[42949373.510000] io scheduler deadline registered
[42949373.510000] io scheduler cfq registered
[42949373.510000] TCP cubic registered
[42949373.510000] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[42949373.510000] Initialized stdio console driver
[42949373.510000] Console initialized on /dev/tty0
[42949373.510000] console [tty0] enabled
[42949373.510000] Initializing software serial port version 1
[42949373.510000] console [mc-1] enabled
[42949373.510000]  ubda: unknown partition table
[42949373.510000] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[42949373.510000] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
[42949373.510000] VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly.
 * version 2.86 booting
 * Entering runlevel: 2


Ubuntu 5.10 "Breezy Badger" (none) tty0

(none) login: uml
(none) login: root
df^H^H^H




 * Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
 * no more processes left in this runlevel

Ubuntu 5.10 "Breezy Badger" (none) tty0

(none) login: uml

Ubuntu 5.10 "Breezy Badger" (none) tty0

(none) login: uml
(none) login: 
Login timed out after 60 seconds.
```

Update:  I tried the same as the answer, and got this error. Note I built 2.6.27 kernel in 32-bit i386.

```
[42949373.510000] VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly.
modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.27/modules.dep: No such file or directory

INIT: version 2.88 booting
INIT: Entering runlevel: 2
[42949373.660000] Serial line 0 assigned device '/dev/pts/8'

INIT: Id "c0" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 (none) tty0

(none) login: root

Login incorrect
```

Comment: Make sure that devtmpfs is being created. I was missing that step. Minimal buildroot image: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372207/32558

Answer (score 0):

I have edit my Answer!

**This is what i did and it works for me!**

build the kernel

```
# wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.39.tar.gz

# bunzip2 linux-2.6.39.tar.gz

# make ARCH=um defconfig

# make ARCH=um
```

Download root-fs

```
# wget http://fs.devloop.org.uk/filesystems/Debian-Squeeze/Debian-Squeeze-AMD64-root_fs.bz2

# bunzip2 Debian-Squeeze-AMD64-root_fs.bz2
```

Start UML Linux

```
./vmlinux ubda=/root/Debian-Squeeze-AMD64-root_fs mem=128m umid=debian
...
...
...
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 (none) tty0

(none) login: root
Last login: Wed Jan 30 19:57:33 UTC 2013 on tty0
Linux (none) 2.6.39 #1 Wed Jan 30 11:49:25 PST 2013 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
root@(none):~# whoami
root
```

Comment: I did both. Actually I was following this page: http://web2.clarkson.edu/class/cs644/kernel/setup/uml/uml.html.  But still got the same problem.

Comment: Are you booting from you new UML kernel or just playing with chroot?

Comment: Post some error messages and dig in log files.. without them i don't think any body can help...

Comment: Hi, I have updated my Question with the full log of the log in session.  Also, I was wondering if there is any logs I can check when the login failed/not accepted?  I couldn't find anything under the directory I started "linux".

Comment: check /var/log/messages, /var/log/secure etc.. also did you create all devices in /dev dir?

Comment: Try this  ./linux mem=128M ubda=/nobackup/hxu2/uml/debian-2 init=/bin/bash

Comment: It seem your root-fs has issue!

Comment: ok.  I will try to re-build my root-fs.  But how do I do it differently this time? I was following this page that I think is good: http://web2.clarkson.edu/class/cs644/kernel/setup/uml/uml.html

Comment: Did you see my UML in answer section try that root-fs it should work! and compare with your one

Comment: I have looked at your updated answer.  There are 2 things are different for me:  1) my UML kernel was 2.6.27 built with SUBARCH=i386.  2) i downloaded x86, not AMD64 root-fs from that page. Then I tried the same but still cannot login.  See my updated question.

Comment: One thing I wanted to note:  I don't have root permission on this machine where I ran the UML.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731847/user-mode-linux-unreliable-on-2-6-27-47-with-subarch-i386/17734767#17734767).  And then stumbled into the answer, which at least works for me.

Which host version are you running?  I found that with 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5 as the host, these versions of UML do work, whereas they don't with a 2.6.9-89.0.11.ELlargesmp host.

Why?  ... I don't know :(